# Syntax in the Python API

Tags: python, scripting

I am a newbie with Python scripting in Blender.  Lately, I have been browsing the Blender API documentation to figure out how to incorporate certain features into my scripts for Python.  However, I am confused because I feel as though the documentation fails to provide the examples necessary to understand how the methods provided in the library would actually be used in a script.

For example, I am interested in (as part of a "poll" function in an operator) determining whether a object has been modified.  I found the method [bpy.types.Object.is_modified](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77_1/bpy.types.Object.html?highlight=bpy.types.object#bpy.types.Object.is_modified).  Unfortunately, I can't make heads or tails of the information provided, as I know I can't just type in bpy.types.Object.is_modified to determine whether an object has been modified.  It throws an exception in the Python console, even when I type in "scene" and "settings" for the parameters for the function (the parameters are listed as "scene" and "settings" in the library's function definition).  I have tried leaving in "Object" in the command, and have also tried replacing "Object" with either the name of the object or a variable being used to represent the object.  Similarly, I am not really sure how any methods in bpy.types.Object are normally called, because, although I do not really know, I get the impression that they are normally called using prefixes other than "bpy.types".  Can someone please help me?

EDIT: Here is a picture showing what I have tried and the exceptions that I have received:
[image]

Comment: what is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a closer look at the syntax the command needs.

*bpy.types.Object* is just the general class.  In basic programming terms, *bpy.types.Object* is only a blueprint for what an object should be. You want the instance, or copy, of the class that refers specifically to 'Plane' .
In your case, this would be: **bpy.types.Object(bpy.data.objects['Plane'])**

Secondly, look again at the API for *is_modified()*. When it says *(scene, settings)* it doesn't mean those literal words.

- *scene* refers to the actual class of your scene. You want **bpy.data.scenes['Scene']** (or whatever name is shown in the outliner)
- *settings* has two options already determined for you. In the API, it says "*(enum in ['PREVIEW', 'RENDER'])*," meaning either of those words is what goes in the *settings* place. PREVIEW checks the object's modifier settings for preview mode, and RENDER checks settings for render mode (what appears when you press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>)

So, to do it right:

```
import bpy
scene = bpy.data.scenes['Scene']
plane = bpy.data.objects['Plane']
```

Then:

```
bpy.types.Object(plane).is_modified(scene, 'PREVIEW')  OR
bpy.types.Object(plane).is_modified(scene, 'RENDER')
```

Comment: what about plain old plane.is_modified(scene, 'PREVIEW') All objects in the `bpy.data.objects` collection will be instances of type `bpy.types.Object`